# set /p from input file works only for first line in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a very simple problem in windows batch programming, yet I did not find the answer in the existing questions.

I want to fill the content of 3 variables with input from a text file (3 lines, one for each variable), and use `set /p`. But it seems this works only for the first line, not the others.

Here is a reproducible example:

I launch this batch file (test.bat):

```
@echo off
(
 set /p Line1=
 set /p Line2=
 set /p Line3=
)<%1 
echo I read the following parameter from your %1 config file:
echo -- Content of line 1:           %Line1%
echo -- Content of line 2:           %Line2%
echo -- Content of line 3:           %Line3%
```

The argument file is test.txt:

```
The line 1
The line 2
The line 2 copied
```

Then, I just launch `'test.bat test.txt'`, with the following result:

I read the following parameter from your test.txt config file:

```
-- Content of line 1:           The line 1
-- Content of line 2:
-- Content of line 3:
```

Why do the lines 2 and 3 from test.txt are not takken up and the correspnding variables line2 and line3 empty?

Comment: Interesting. I can't replicate your problem; all three lines correctly display for me. My only suggestion right now is to make sure your text file contains what you think it contains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem if `test.txt` contains Unix line breaks `0x0A`, and it works if it contains windows line breaks (`0x0D 0x0A`). So if that is also the source of your problem convert the line breaks in your `test.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a FOR /f loop:

```
@echo off
setlocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "linenum=1"
for /f %%i in (%1) do (
    set "line!linenum!=%%i"
    set /a "linenum = !linenum! + 1"
)

echo %line1%
echo %line2%
echo %line3%
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding [wero's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36400645/1012053) a bit. The solution is indeed to make sure that all lines in the file end with CRLF (\r\n) or LFCR (\n\r). The discussion below explains why.

SET /P behavior is not entirely intuitive. The following description of the behavior is taken from a DosTips thread at http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2160.

**Reading characters:**

Characters are read from the input stream and put in a character buffer until one of three conditions is true:

- Condition 1: The last 2 read char are CRLF or LFCR. (a complete line)
- Condition 2: There are 1023 characters in the char buffer. (buffer
  full)
- Condition 3: A timeout, usually caused by end-of-stream.
  (time-out error-condition) *Note - not sure if there really is a timeout condition, the jury is still out on this one*

**Processing the char buffer:**

- All control-characters from the end of the char-buffer are discarded
  (possible data loss)
- If there is a NUL character in the char buffer, then all
  characters following the first NUL in the char buffer will be
  discarded (data loss)

**Moving from char buffer to Var.**

- If char buffer is empty report error condition:
  ...set errorlevel to 1 (meaning No value entered)
- If charbuffer is not empty:
  ... Move the string from char buffer to the variable named in the set/p command.

SET /P is done and returns control to the batchfile.

Note that The longest line that can be processed reliably is 1021 bytes (not including the terminating CRLF or LFCR).